# How to get rid of wierd NA rows in each cell of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a database as a dataframe named 'data' which constitutes 500 objects and 2 variables. 
in fact

```
dim(data)
```

returns

```
[1] 500  2
```

and

```
str(data)
```

returns

```
    'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
    $ Diagnosis          : chr  "D1" "D2" "D3" "D4" ...
    $ Type               : Factor w/ 8 levels "T1","T2",..: 6 4 1 6 1 4 4 4 5 5 ...
```

But, when I'm trying to retrieve the value of 'Type' for a specific 'Diagnosis', say, 'D4', 11 weird NA values appear in addition to 'Type' value. In fact, it seems that in each cell of this data frame there is a vector of 12 values of which 11 are NA have come out of thin air. 
In turn,

```
data[data$Diagnosis=='D4','Type']
```

returns:

```
    [1] <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>        
    [7] <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         T6
```

intrestingly:

```
data[data$Diagnosis=='D4',]
```

returns:

```
    Diagnosis         Type
NA              <NA>         <NA>
NA.1            <NA>         <NA>
NA.2            <NA>         <NA>
NA.3            <NA>         <NA>
NA.4            <NA>         <NA>
NA.5            <NA>         <NA>
NA.6            <NA>         <NA>
NA.7            <NA>         <NA>
NA.8            <NA>         <NA>
NA.9            <NA>         <NA>
NA.10           <NA>         <NA>
503              D4           T6
```

The dataframe had been created in excel and then I imported it to R studio, I have done a lot of alterations on the dataframe since.

I have two questions:

1. Where did these NAs come from and how can I delete them?
   In fact, I want `data[data$Diagnosis=='D4','Type']`

to return:

```
[1] T6
```

and:

```
data[data$Diagnosis=='D4',]
```

to retun:

```
                   Diagnosis       Type  
  [row number]         D4           T6
```

- I can not use omit.na(data) complete.cases() for the whole dataframe, as I have some legitimate NAs that I don't want to remove

  2. how can I set more than one value to a cell of a data frame. let's assume that 1# person has 2 concomitant diagnoses. how can I store both values of 'D1' and 'D2' in the 'diagnosis' of the 1# person?

Comment: These questions aren't very clear. For Q1) What do you want to do with the data? Remove all rows with NA in each column? Remove all rows with NA in at least one column? For Q2) Where is the second diagnosis that you want to put into this data frame coming from? In another data.frame? In a vector? In your head? In the same data frame?

Comment: Q1) I want      data[data$Diagnosis=='D4','Type']     to return       'T6'      without those NAs  Q2) let's assume it is in my head, not in any other data structure

Comment: What happens if you use `data[data$Diagnosis=='D4',]['Type']` ?

Comment: data[data$Diagnosis %in% 'D4','Type']

Comment: Yeah but if there's a row with only one NA, ensuring no NAs in the Type column would require removing non-NA data from the Diagnosis column, unless you specify some pattern for reassigning non-NA values to different rows.

Comment: @deepseefan it returns:
NA            <NA>
NA.1          <NA>
NA.2          <NA>
NA.3          <NA>
NA.4          <NA>
NA.5          <NA>
NA.6          <NA>
NA.7          <NA>
NA.8          <NA>
NA.9          <NA>
NA.10         <NA>
503              T6
>

Comment: @Hooman, if you edit your post adding the output of a `dput(data)`, it might be easier to see what's happening with your data, and a solution.

Comment: @MatthewR that works fine for returning the desired values, thanks. but how can I correct the whole data frame?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan unfortunately, I can not omit all NAs because I have some legitimate NAs that i don't want to remove

Answer (score 0):

I think this explanation will be helpful.
As you can see `Type` column is a not a `character`,it is a `factor`
so in R,behind the scenes it is consider as `categorical field`.as you can see it shows levels as integers.so if you try to access the value it returns the level,not the value. what you need is convert `Type` column to characters first.after that do the operation

```
df$Type <- as.character(df$Type)
```